# How to drop the existing table from the EJB DB and create the the same table in to the DB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm struggling with this exception.

out put :

> Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Column 'DATE' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'DATE' is not a column in the target table.
>
> at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)

In the NewsEntity.java  I had declare the date variable.but it showing me exception is like above mentioned.

The NewsEntity.java - image
[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/omupz.png][1]

the PostMessage.java file - image
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwFAO.png][2]

I'm declare getters and setter for date variable and set the date method in PostMessage.java file

Comment: Please do not post source code as an image but include it in your question text

Comment: The column names `date` and `time` are SQL 92 reserved words.  They would be a poor choice for column names.  Instead, name them something useful like `publication_date`.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the hibernate to `create-drop` but all data will be erased. other options are :

- validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- update: update the schema.
- create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- create-drop: drop the schema when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly, typically when the application is stopped.